# polymorphic binary search tree

Tags: java, string, binary-tree, polymorphism

I have 2 classes, NonEmptyTree and EmptyTree that implement the Tree interface. `toString()` method in NonEmptyTree class should return a string: `key=>value key=>value key>value` etc...
I do not know how to remove last space at end of result. 
EDIT: I cannot use any methods in the String class, and I cannot compare anything to null.

```
public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        result+=(this.left.toString());
        result+=this.key;
        result+="=>";
        result+=this.value;
        result+=" ";
        result+=this.right.toString();
        return result;
    }
```

I've tried having a variable for the class that indicates if a NonEmptyTree instance is the largest in the current tree, but console displayed same string.

for example, the string would look like this:

```
"7=>seven 10=>ten 12=>twelve 15=>fifteen 16=>sixteen 17=>seventeen 20=>twenty 30=>thirty "
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.trim()`:

```
return result.trim()
```

BTW. if you do a lot of `String` additions it's better to use `StringBuilder` and its method `append()` instead of adding multiple `String`s with `+`.

Comment: i've tried trim.. it does not work. I'm not allowed to use any methods from String class. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(this.left.toString());
    result.append(this.key);
    result.append("=>");
    result.append(this.value);
    result.append(" ");
    result.append(this.right.toString());
    return result.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: The default capacity for `StringBuilder` is 16 characters. Consider initializing it with a larger initial capacity to prevent incremental reallocation and copying.

Comment: Fair point ... but even given that it would be better than what he's doing ;)

Comment: @seh: The problem here is that we would need to know how big the resulting string will be, since we don't want to create a too big buffer unnecessary.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys. I'm not allowed to use any methods of the String class unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply add an 'if'?  See below:

```
public String toString() 
{ 
    String result = ""; 
    result+=(this.left.toString());
    result+=this.key; result+="=>";
    result+=this.value; 
    if (this.right!=null)  // Just add this, so it doesn't add an extra space if no right result exists
    {
        result+=" ";
        result+=this.right.toString();
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: I think you need to swap the two statements inside the if condition.  If I understand it correctly, if the right branch is not null, then the output should have a space followed by that branch.

Comment: Quite right Bill. I copy/pasted it too hastily from the original post.  It has been corrected.  Thank you.